# SQL variable in PHP

Tags: php, sql

I have several dropdown menu's, filled with data out of the database:

- Customer   (first- lastname)
- Bike       (Brand/Model)
- Bikenumber

I can select the Customer. But on that point, I only want to see the bikes (brand/model) of that customer. Once that one has been selected, I want to select the bikenumber(always 1 number)

in SQL it would be:

```
SELECT brand, model FROM Bike WHERE CustomerID = 1;
```

But, the customer ID(or name??) is based on the first dropdown menu so it must be an variable. But how do i do this? My code for the dropdown:

```
<?php
    echo '<select name="value">';                                             
    echo '<option value="">Selecteer fiets</option>'; //Haalt fietsen van klant op uit de database.
    while ($row = $resultfiets->fetch_object()) {
        echo '<option fiets"' . $row->merk .'">';
        echo $row->merk;
        echo'</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';
?>
```

$queryfiets: `$queryfiets = "SELECT merk, model FROM fiets";`

$resultfiets: `$resultfiets = $link->query($queryfiets);`

Comment: Shouldn't `'<option fiets"' . $row->merk .'">'` be `'<option value="' . $row->merk .'">'`?